# RPM spec scripting compliance and how to test it

Tags: rpm, rhel

I maintain some spec files for rpms  on rhel5 and rhel6, but I always struggle with more complex testing within the spec file. Often I resign writing the config logic in a perl or bash script that is executed within the rpm upon installation.

Now I struggle with this simple not equal test, I believed the scripting logic was close to bash, but at least some work for bash. If I remove that if test it all works.

```
echo "verifying base:%{smm_public_base} against %{smm_public}";
# if smm_public is not the same as smm_public_base we must sublink
if [ %{smm_public_base} -ne %{smm_public} ]; then
  echo "smm_public_base:%{smm_public_base} is not the same as smm_public:%{smm_public} so we need to soflink it"
  if [ -L %{smm_public_base ]; then
    rm -rf %{smm_public_base}
  fi
  ln -s %{smm_public} %{smm_public_base} || :
fi
```

I've tried:

```
if [ %{smm_public_base} != %{smm_public} ]; then
```

and

```
if [ "%{smm_public_base}" != "%{smm_public}" ]; then
```

Those give errors like this

```
verifying base:/opt/s3public against /opt/app/s3public
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.29711: line 60: syntax error: unexpected end of file
error: %post(secana_smm2_SEB_PROD-r250-225.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 2
```

So I've been searching for a primer on how to write scripting logic within a spec file, but found very little except for simple testing in the 
[Fedora RPM guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/index.html)

Anyone having some best practices here. Opensuse says look at a redhat package.

Thanks

Comment: And that if is line 60 of the script mentioned on that error message? Does the script end after that or does it continue as you would expect? I don't see how those contents could be the problem this sounds more like something else is getting in the way of the script somehow. Can you include the contents of that script the error complains about?

Comment: Line 60 is the line above, if I uncomment it it and its 'fi' all goes fine. My problem is that this works in bash(If I change the variables into more bash friendy ones). It is here on rhel5.10

Comment: You are suggesting that with the `-ne` test your logic doesn't work but the script does and with the `!=` test you get that syntax error for EOF? And that if you comment out that test entirely the internal linking code works fine? `-ne` is for numbers so it isn't surprising that it doesn't work for strings (it should be giving you an error in your output though I would have thought).

Comment: All suggestions give the same error. I've tried removing the 2 level ifs. but same error. I find it strange that a so simple condition should fail.

Comment: You get that EOF syntax error even without the `if` lines? It throws it on the `rm` or `ln` line at that point I assume? Please post the script from `/var/tmp` that the error message mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, do not know why it works if you comment out the if loop.

```
if [ -L %{smm_public_base ]; then
```

this was missinng a closure which have been missinng all the time..

```
if [ -L %{smm_public_base} ]; then
```

Sorry to have wasted Your time, but why complain on line 60 and not 63?